# Cannot load torchvision despite it being installed

Tags: python, pip, pytorch

I have installed pytorch and torchvision using:

```
conda install pytorch-cpu -c pytorch
pip install torchvision
```

when I try to run the following in spyder:

```
import torch
import torchvision
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
```

I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-2-0bf25e9dac67>", line 2, in <module>
    import torchvision

  File "C:\Users\lkoefoed\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-package\torchvision\__init__.py", line 2, in <module> 
from torchvision import datasets

  File "C:\Users\lkoefoed\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torchvision\datasets\__init__.py", line 1, in <module> 
from .lsun import LSUN, LSUNClass

  File "C:\Users\lkoefoed\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torchvision\datasets\lsun.py", line 2, in <module> 
from PIL import Image

  File "C:\Users\lkoefoed\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 56, in <module> 
from . import _imaging as core

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Comment: did you check whether the specified files are present on your hard disk, and can be seen from the $PATH$ variable?

Comment: All the files specified are there. How can I make sure they are seen by the $PATH$ variable?

Comment: Actually, narrowing it down, there should be a _imaging.c or .py file in PIL..

Comment: [made into a answer]

Answer (score 4):

Fixed by running:

```
conda install pytorch-cpu -c pytorch 
pip install torchvision
```

Deleting the PIL and pillow folders in site-packages, then running:

```
pip install pillow
```

Comment: Didn't work for me, there seem to be multiple causes for this issue

Comment: what worked for me was running:
conda install torchvision -c soumith

Comment: @Quastiat: so essentially you downgraded to torchvision-0.2.1 (from say >=0.4.*) This is a hellish problem. Cuda10.1 + torch > 1.1.0 and torchvision > 0.3.0 (doesn't seem to work unless you downgrade torchvision)

Answer (score 0):

conda:

```
conda install torchvision -c pytorch
```

This worked perfectly for me